# is there any equivalent for PHP's "??" operation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

javascript has the same struct as PHP's associative array named Object. in PHP when we want to check if this key is set or not we can use this operator that can lead a concise code instead of using nested if blocks:

```
$b = $a['parentKey']['childKey']['grandChildKey'] ?? '';
```

that means if 'grandChildKey' and all parent keys of that key is set and has a value other than the null return that value, otherwise returns an empty string.
is there any similar syntax in js?

Comment: With a transpiler, `a?.parentKey?.childKey?.grandChildKey || ''`

Comment: @CertainPerformance is this js pure code?

Comment: Yes, it's stage 4 (finished proposal), but it isn't widely implemented, so to use it, you'll need a transpiler (or a more verbose workaround)

Comment: You can also use `??` instead of `||` (again, transpiler needed) in case the value is falsey but not undefined

Comment: can you describe how it is possible? how can I use (install) the transpiler to make this code working?

Comment: Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)